# Prevent PhpStorm from arranging constructor arguments like a table

Tags: php, phpstorm

The arguments of my constructor are written on different lines. When I press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L to format code PhpStorm adds spaces to the shorter argument types so that the columns become of equal length.

I can't figure out which code style settings is responsible for that. I want to disable it.

**What it does:**

```
public function __construct(
    AdvertisingDetailsAdapter $advertisingDetailsAdapter,
    AdAccountService          $adAccountService,
    BusinessManagerService    $businessManagerService
)
```

**What I want:**

```
public function __construct(
    AdvertisingDetailsAdapter $advertisingDetailsAdapter,
    AdAccountService $adAccountService,
    BusinessManagerService $businessManagerService
)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the relevant configuration toggle is shown on the picture

[image]

If the picture does not load:

1. Press **Alt+F7** to open the **Settings** (or choose **File => Settings** from the main menu)
2. In the settings dialog, navigate to **Editor => Code Style => PHP** (from the left pane)
3. In the right pane, choose the tab **Wrapping and Brances**
4. Inside that tab, untoggle the checkmark (tick) from the setting **Function declaration parameters => Align when multiline**

Comment: Image is not loading. Can you write down how to do it from Menu?